# Is there a way to remove italic style from <i> tag without effecting document.execCommand("italic")

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable, execcommand

I'd like to make text in `<i>` tag not appear italic in a contenteditable div.

However, as you can see in the code snippet below, if I add `font-style:normal` to italic style, `document.execCommand('italic')` to unitalicize no longer works, as the browser correctly detects that the text is not italic.

Would there be any way to have both unitalic-looking `<i>` and a way to unitalicize?

```js
function italicize(){
  document.execCommand("italic");
}
```

```css
i{
  font-style:normal;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true>a<i>b</i>c</div>

<button onclick=italicize()>italic</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! for that specific purpose HTML have tag name `span`, Why not using it

Comment: @Awais To provide more context, think of a note editor where the note is already made with italics and bolds. With external scripts, I am changing the way italic tags look. However, doing that makes the user unable to unitalicize.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) says that `execCommand` is obsolete and should not be used. I don't think that helps a lot though, since they don't say what you need to replace it with.

Comment: @yoonchaelee Oh got yeah Sorry i miss understood :(, A simple way is toggle class on click which have italic font-style.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function italicize() {
  let myDiv = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
  myDiv.style.fontStyle.localeCompare("italic") ? myDiv.style.fontStyle = "italic" : myDiv.style.fontStyle = "normal";
}
```

```css
i {
  font-style: normal;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv" contenteditable=true>a<i>b</i>c</div>
  <button onclick="italicize()">italic</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Is this what you are looking for? #newToStackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this can be by creating a specific style rule that removes the default italic style from all `<i>` elements inside a `<div>`.

Then, with `querySelectorAll` you can target all the `<i>` that live inside a `<div contenteditable="true">` attribute and make the text italicized by toggling a class:

```js
function italicize() {
  let contentDivs = document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"] > i')
  for (let div of contentDivs) {
    div.classList.toggle('add-italic');
  }
}
```

```css
div > i {
  font-style: normal;
  color: red;
}

.add-italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">a<i>b</i>c</div>

<button onclick="italicize()">italic</button>
```

Comment: How would I be able to do this not to the entire div, but only to texts I selected?

Comment: You would have to figure out a way to select the particular element. Could you clarify a bit more? Perhaps add an example?

Comment: Select text by clicking and dragging over. Not italicize/unitalicize entire contenteditable div. I could try selecting by using window.getSelection(), but because selected text may not be entire nodes, I'm not sure how I'd go about that

Answer (score 0):

More Solutions for this problem.

## Change Node with innerText

```js
function unitalicize(){
   var element = document.getElementsByTagName("i")[0];
   var span = document.createElement("span");
   while(element.firstChild){
           span.appendChild(element.firstChild);
   }
   element.parentElement.replaceChild(span,element)
}
function italicize(){
  var element = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
  var i = document.createElement("i");
  while(element.firstChild){
     i.appendChild(element.firstChild);
  }
  element.parentElement.replaceChild(i,element)
}
```

```css
i{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true>a<i>b</i>c</div>

<button onclick=unitalicize()>unitalicize()</button>
<button onclick=italicize()>italicize()</button>
```